# Вывести названия категорий вместо id

Tags: php, yii2, view

Здравствуйте. Подскажите пожалуйста, как вывести название категории вместо id?
Как это сделать в GridView я разобрался. Вот так:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        'title',
        [
            'attribute' => 'category_id',
            'label' => 'Category',
            'value' => 'category.title',
        ],
        'description,
        ...
```

А вот как вывести название "обычным" способом так и не нашел.
Имеем view файл, например, article.php:

```
<?= $article->title ?>
<?= $article->category_id ?>
<?= $article->description ?>
```

В модели Articles:

```
public function getCategory()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Category::className(),['id' => 'category_id']);
}
```

В модели Categories:

```
public function getArticles()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Articles::className(), ['category_id' => 'id']);
}
```

Может я туплю, но очевидные решения в голову не приходят.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вывода используйте

```
$article->category->title;
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо. Под устал я видимо к вечеру.

Comment: @AlexeyDunin Пожалуйста. От усталости и не такие косяки делаются =)